# method range of object _worksheet failed named range

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rangeForCode As range, rngLookupRange As range

Dim row As Integer, stock As Integer
Dim result As Integer
Dim drugCodePC As Integer
Dim qty As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

drugCodePC = CInt(DrugCode2.Value)
qty = CInt(Quantity.Value)

'Populating the drug name
Set ws = Worksheets("Drug Record")
ws.Select

*Set rangeForCode = ws.range("DrugCodeInventory")*
row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(drugCodePC, rangeForCode, 1)
Set rngLookupRange = ws.range("Inventory")
stock = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(drugCodePC, rngLookupRange, 3, False)
result = stock + qty
'MsgBox (row)
ws.Cells(row + 1, 3).Value = result

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload PurchaseForm 
End Sub
```

This keeps throwing the error "method range of object _worksheet failed named range".
The error occurs at the **. I know it has something to do with the named ranged because previously, when i wrote the range of cells ie. "A1:A215" it works. I've checked the name range and it looks right. The name of the named ranged is also correct. I've tried to activate the workbook first but the error is still thrown.

The named ranged is:

```
= OFFSET(DrugCodeInventory!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(DrugCodeInventory!$A:$A)-1,1)
```

I only want to select the first column in my worksheet dynamically.

Comment: Try using a different name for your range (ie. not the same name as the sheet)

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of confused. Are you saying that the range `DrugCodeInventory` refers to `= OFFSET(DrugCodeInventory!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(DrugCodeInventory!$A:$A)-1,1)` ?

Comment: did either of the answers help? (if they did then up them +1) - if either meant that your problem got fixed then mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this in the Immediate window does it work?

```
application.Goto Worksheets("Drug Record").range("DrugCodeInventory")
```

If it doesn't run then try deleting the named range and creating a new one.

Please also try explicitly qualifying this section of your code:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet '<added full qualification here

drugCodePC = CInt(DrugCode2.Value)
qty = CInt(Quantity.Value)

'Populating the drug name
Set ws = Excel.thisworkbook.Worksheets("Drug Record") '<added full qualification here
ws.Select

*Set rangeForCode = ws.range("DrugCodeInventory")*
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the below **isNameRngExist** function which will return true when the name range **"DrugCodeInventory"** exist and then you can proceed with further manipulation.

```
Function isNameRngExist(myRng As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    isNameRngExist = Len(ThisWorkbook.Names(TheName).Name) <> 0
End Function
```